# CakePHP Validation errors are not appearing

Tags: cakephp-1.3

If I'm not mistaken, CakePHP's validation errors are supposed to be rendered automatically below the input field that they correspond to.  Mine aren't doing this.  The validation errors are in the Model->validationErrors array, but they are not being printed.  I don't have a beforeValidate method for this model (I do have a beforeSave method, which return true whatever).

In other news, Cake's SQL log isn't showing for me either, with debug on 2.

I'm using Cake version 1.3.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is a problem in the $validate array in your model. More code pls?